# Koma-script and glossaries package

Tags: formatting, koma-script, glossaries

This has driven me crazy for some time now and I finally found out the origin of my problem. Now I would like to solve it.

In my thesis document, I add acronyms using the glossaries package. This all works, however I could never figure out why my Acronym items were formatted in Sans Serif, here is a coded MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

%preamble
\usepackage[colorlinks,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,% create 'acronym' glossary type
            nomain,% 'main' glossary not needed as using 'acronym'
            style=altlist, % use altlist style
            toc, % add the glossary to the table of contents
           ]{glossaries}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short-desc}

\renewcommand*{\glsseeitemformat}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentrytext{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}


\begin{filecontents}{glossaryTest.tex}
% Glossary Entries
\newacronym[description={This is just for show}
]{foo}{foo}{don't really know where foo stand for}

\newacronym[description={And another showoff description}
]{bar}{bar}{beyond all recognition}
\end{filecontents}

\loadglsentries{glossaryTest.tex}


\begin{document}


\chapter{blabla}

Just testing whether I can refer to some \gls{foo} or \gls{bar}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

And an example image:
[image]

Which, as you surely agree, looks horrible.

After fiddling forever with *all* my packages and *all* my style stuffs, I finally changed the last thing I would think influence the look of my glossary... it was the koma-script scrreprt documentclass I am using, if I change this to report this is the output:

[image]

As I like a *lot* of the features koma-script scrreprt offers me, my question is how can I format or tweak something so that my glossary looks as in the second image, whilst still using the scrreprt class.

Anyone?

Comment: let your `\sfdefault` be `\rmdefault`.

Comment: Yes, this works. However everything I like about scrreprt (for example: serif titles and the serif captions I use) change with it.

I would like to *specifically* edit the font in the glossaries, not a general setting for my entire document.

Comment: Do it *before* your list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `\textnormal` instead of `\textmd` when redefining `\glsnamefont`.

```
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
```

Another -- and perhaps more consistent -- way is to redefine the formatting used by the labels of description lists, which is also used by `glossaries`' labels:

```
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont}
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, the latter indeed seems more consistent. Will check it out. Thanks for the support!