# change font of glossary entry (glossaries, scrreprt)

Tags: fonts, koma-script, glossaries

When using glossaries to display acronyms within a scrreprt document, the acronyms in the list of acronyms will be printed in bold sans serif. I would like to have the (bold) serif font, however. How can this be achieved?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{../acronyms-gls.tex}
\begin{document}
   This is some text with acronyms: an \acs{AOFS} and an \acs{AOM} are often used for \acs{CPA}.
   \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

acronyms-gls.tex:

```
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{AOFS}{AOFS}{acousto-optic frequency shifter}
\newacronym{AOM}{AOM}{acuosto-optic modulator}
\newacronym{CPA}{CPA}{chirped-pulse amplification}
```

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201858/34759 working for you?

Comment: Oh yes, somehow the search didn't spit out that question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as moospit [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289885/change-font-of-glossary-entry-glossaries-scrreprt?noredirect=1#comment701367_289885), [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201858/34759) solved my problems, I simply added

```
\addtokomafont{descriptionlabel}{\rmfamily}
```

to my preamble since glossaries inherits descriptionlabel for the glossary entries.